# how to find any words between 3 to 6 letters long containing either yes or no using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried:

```
(no|yes)\w{3,6}
```

but this basically works, but there is some catch in it. when I say between 3 to 6 characters long, it doesn't count yes or no.

for example: if I have a word yesss, it wont match with it, even though it has only 5 characters. because it starts counting after 'yes'. but it'll match if i have 'yessssss'.

what is the correct regular expression for it?

Comment: Using `/\b(?=\w*(?:yes|no))\w{3,6}\b/`

Comment: @Wiktor it only gets the first word.

Comment: No probem, `text.match(/\b(?=\w*(?:yes|no))\w{3,6}\b/ig)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
const matches = text.match(/\b(?=\w*(?:yes|no))\w{3,6}\b/ig);
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=\w*(?:yes|no))` - after any zero or more word chars, there must be `yes` or `no`
- `\w{3,6}` - three to six word chars
- `\b` - word boundary.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "abcno and abcyes and abyesno";
const matches = text.match(/\b(?=\w*(?:yes|no))\w{3,6}\b/ig);
console.log(matches);
```

If you only want to match words consisting of letters:

```js
const text = "abcno and abcyes and abyesno";
const matches = text.match(/\b(?=\p{L}*(?:yes|no))\p{L}{3,6}\b/igu);
console.log(matches);
```

The `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter and `u` enables this pattern support in an ECMAScript 2018+ compliant regex engine. If you only work with ASCII letters, replace `\p{L}` with `[a-zA-Z]` and remove `u` flag.